# Issue with std::atomic<double>::compareexchangeweak(): no matching member function error by the compiler

Tags: c++11

Trying to run some multi threaded bit of code and clang llvm compiler complains that `std::atomic<double>::compare_exchange_weak()` does not have the correct number of arguments. Can anyone please help?

thanks
Amine

```
static std::atomic<int> counter(0);
std::atomic<double> x = {0.0000000003};


template class std::vector<double>;

struct TestVector
{
    std::vector<double> Vect;
    explicit TestVector(std::size_t n) : Vect(std::vector<double>(n))
    {
        for(auto i = 0; i< Vect.size(); ++i)
        {
            Vect[i] = std::cos(i*M_PI/2.0);
        }
    }
};

const TestVector Z(30000);

void TestOnAtomics()
{
    int j { 0};
    double y = (Z.Vect)[j] + 0.00000005;
    const double u = 1.22222222;
    while(!(x.compare_exchange_weak(y,u)) && j<((Z.Vect).size() - 1))
    {
        ++counter;
        x.store(std::move((Z.Vect)[j]), std::memory_order::memory_order_seq_cst);
        ++j;
        std::cout << "\nMy value is " << x << " and that of y is: " << y << "\n";
        y = (Z.Vect)[j];
    };
}
```

Comment: What did it tell you the candidates were?

Comment: Also, the code in your question is missing the `#include` lines.

Comment: Not familiar with atomic, but acording to the documentation I've found, [std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) takes 3 arguments in C++11. You've given 2.

Comment: @Chipster thats the free function, OP is using the [member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

Comment: please include the full error

Comment: not reproduceable (if <atomic> included). You also have signed/unsigned mismatch for comparisons in your code.

Comment: error: no matching member function for call to 'store'
candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided

the above is the error message I get. the third argument to the member function I get is default sequentially consistent std::memory_model

Comment: @Ben Voigt, yes sorry I forgot to include the #include<atomic> header..

Comment: I realised the Debugger was playing funny when I deleted/put back the watch on my variables. It works just fine now. Sorry for raising a wrong alert!  Matter closed now